# MATLAB Trouble- Error help- Converting integer to binary

Tags: matlab

How do I fix this? I'm writing a program to convert integers to binary, and I Keep getting an error saying: 
     bina(100)
     "Error using idivide>idivide_check (line 65)
     At least one argument must belong to an integer class.

```
 Error in idivide (line 41)
 idivide_check(a,b);

 Error in bina (line 15)
       d = idivide(d,2);"
```

Here's my code:

```
 function [n] = Bina(d)
% bina is a function that converts integers to binary
% Week 11, Question 18

   n = [];
   if d >=(2^16 -1)       
       fprintf('This number is too big')   
   else
       while d ~= 0
           r=rem(d,2);
           n=[r n];
           d = idivide(d,2);
       end
   end
end

%bina(100)
%bina(1002)
%bina(52601)
%bina(200090)
```

Comment: I see no input validation. How are you making sure `d` is always an integer?

Comment: How do I change this?

Comment: I input D as an integer of my choice

Comment: Consider [`isinteger`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isinteger.html) as a method to validate your inputs. The linked documentation also links you to the various integer data types and commands to convert (e.g. `int8`, `uint8`, etc.)

Comment: As far as my code, what does that look like? Sorry, I'm a matlab newb, and don't know how to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are putting in the number into your function, MATLAB automatically casts the result to `double`.  [`idivide`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/idivide.html) requires an **integer**.  As such, you need to do a cast to an integer type before converting.  Things like `uint8`, `int8`, `uint16`, `int16` etc. will help.  The `u` stands for **unsigned** which means that all of your numbers are positive, including 0.  Without the `u`, these are **signed** data types and that means your integers can have negative values.  It looks like you only want unsigned data types from your code, so use any of the `u` variants.  Also, your code is checking of `u >= 2^16 - 1`, and so let's use `uint32` to be sure.  Because you're using unsigned data types, you also want to include `2^16 - 1`.  That means that the least significant 16 bits are all set to 1, and since your code (presumably) looks at only the least significant 16 bits, then simply do `u > 2^16 - 1`.

In any case, just do this when calling `Bina` in the command prompt:

```
>> Bina(uint32(100))
>> Bina(uint32(1002))
...
...
```

However, if you want to avoid doing this outside of the function, you can place this casting inside your function to hide this and to make calling simpler... so something like this:

```
 function [n] = Bina(d)
% bina is a function that converts integers to binary
% Week 11, Question 18

   %//******** Change
   d = uint32(d);

   n = [];
   if d >(2^16 -1) %// Change
       fprintf('This number is too big')    
   else
       while d ~= 0
           r=rem(d,2);
           n=[r n];
           d = idivide(d,2);
       end
   end
end
```

Now, you can go ahead and do this in the command prompt:

```
>> Bina(100)
>> Bina(1002)
...
...
```

Comment: Do I do that in the command window?                                                                                  bina(uint32(100));
bina(uint32(1002));
...
...

Comment: @NotAMathMan - Yes that's right, or you can convert it inside the function.  I've edited my post.  That way, you can just do `bina(100)`, etc.